# Bootstrap Popover Temporarily Resizing Table

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a Bootstrap table using PHP and HTML. Here is an example of a cell I am generating including the pop-up:

```
echo '<td colspan="' . $newlength . '" rel="popover" id="example" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Content!!!" data-title="<img src=\'myimage.jpg\' width=\'45\' height=\'30\' /> &nbsp Title">Content!!!</td>';
```

Here is my script:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
trigger: 'click',
    'placement': 'bottom',
    html: 'true' });
```

My problem is that when I activate a popover, the lower row of the table increases in width as if to accommodate the popover, and then resizes to normal after. Is there a way I can stop this happening?

Edit: Have tried to recreate the problem - whilst it isn't exactly the same on bootply (table is resizing horizontally instead of vertically) it is similar. http://www.bootply.com/91456

Comment: Can you by chance duplicate your problem here http://www.bootply.com/?

Comment: @Trevor Have tried to recreate - not exactly the same, table is now resizing columns not rows - probably due to the fact I had to change a lot of the code due to PHP etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `container` option for the `.popover()`...

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    trigger: 'click',
        placement: 'right',
        html: 'true',
        container: '.table'
});
```

This will append the popover element to the table instead of the table cell.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - when I use the container, my popover fails to work at all. Do I need to change anything in the HTML?